# Join não retorna o esperado

Tags: sql, join

Tenho o seguinte esquema:

**tblpessoa** com os campos: idPessoa, nome.

**tblcidade** com os campos: idCidade, codCidade, nome,  idPessoa(fk da tabela tblpessoa), codigoRegiaoCidade(fk da tabela tblregiaoCidade).

**tblregiaoCidade** com os campos: codigoRegiaoCidade, nome.

Entao quero trazer o nome da pessoa, codCidade e o codigoRegiaoCidade(fk da tabela tblregiaoCidade). E faço a seguinte query, mas não retorna nada.

```
SELECT c.codCidade,
  p.nome,
  c.codigoRegiaoCidade

FROM  tblcidade c,
  tblpessoa p
WHERE c.ID_PESSOA = p.ID_PESSOA
AND c.codCidade = 23
AND c.codigoRegiaoCidade = 89 ;
```

Alguém sabe onde está o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Grande bom dia, provavelmente na tabela tblCidades não existe a correspondência de um idPessoa para os códigos do filtro where que você está utilizando, mas também recomendaria usar o left join ele deixará a execução do select mais rápida.

Tenta:

```
SELECT c.codCidade,
       p.nome,
       c.codigoRegiaoCidade

FROM  tblcidade c 
left join tblpessoa p on c.ID_PESSOA = p.ID_PESSOA
where c.codCidade = 23
AND c.codigoRegiaoCidade = 89
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Então, nesse caso existe a correspodência na clausula where, ou seja: WHERE c.ID_PESSOA = p.ID_PESSOA. Se eu tiro essa linha "AND c.codigoRegiaoCidade = 89" a query retorna alguns resultados, se tiro essa linha: "AND c.codCidade = 23" e volto com a anterior, também obtenho resultados, mas se deixo ambas, não retorna absolutamente nada.

Comment: E era para retornar algo? voce tem na tabela tblcidade algum registro com codCidade = 23 e c.codigoRegiaoCidade = 89 ?

Comment: Olá David, sim, existem esses dados no BD.

Comment: No caso grande, essas correspondências devem estar no mesmo registro, tenta colocando ao invés de `and` o `or` e olha se essa condição de codCidade  = 23 e codigoRegiaoCidade = 89 acorrem para o mesmo registro

Answer (score 0):

Essa query funciona para o que voce solicitou! ela está certa.

```
SELECT c.codCidade,
  p.nome,
  c.codigoRegiaoCidade

FROM  tblcidade c,
  tblpessoa p
WHERE c.ID_PESSOA = p.ID_PESSOA
AND c.codCidade = 23
AND c.codigoRegiaoCidade = 89 ;
```

Analisando seu poste e seu comentario na resposta ja existente, o que eu pude perceber é que você deseja um `OR` e não um `AND` nas condições.

tente:

```
SELECT c.codCidade,
       p.nome,
       c.codigoRegiaoCidade

FROM  tblcidade c 
left join tblpessoa p on c.ID_PESSOA = p.ID_PESSOA
where c.codCidade = 23
OR c.codigoRegiaoCidade = 89
```

O resultado da query acima certamente te fará compreender o seu erro.

Caso eu esteja errado peço desculpas.

Comment: Olá David, na verdade eu queria o _AND_ mesmo. O que aconteceu é que na **tblcidade**  tinha o "c.codigoRegiaoCidade = 89", só que ñ tinha esse valor para a pessoa, ou seja pra pessoa estava **null**, logo ñ retornava nada. Obrigado pela ajuda.